# Rewriting pre-written code to implement class. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Few days into Python, I wrote this a day ago to get the gist of Python Grammar. While it might not be efficient it works as i intended.

```
def LongerString():
    if len(String1) == len(String2):
        return len(String1)
    elif len(String1) > len(String2):
        return len(String1)
    elif len(String1) < len(String2):
        return len(String2)

def ShorterString():
    if len(String1) == len(String2):
        return len(String1)
    elif not len(String1) > len(String2):
        return len(String1)
    elif not len(String1) < len(String2):
        return len(String2)


#String1 and 2 from userinput

String1 = input('Input String1\n')
String2 = input('Input String2\n')

#After finishing comparing, evaluates in %

score = 0
for i in range(ShorterString()):
    if String1[i] == String2[i]:
        score += 1
print(score, "/", LongerString(), "Match", float(score / LongerString()) * 100, "%")
```

As my progress goes, decided to re-write this code under single class to 
get better understanding of how class is used. But looks like I'm missing something. Below is my little attempt.

```
class CompareString:

    def LongerString():
        if len(String1) == len(String2):
            return len(String1)
        elif len(String1) > len(String2):
            return len(String1)
        elif len(String1) < len(String2):
            return len(String2)

    def ShorterString():
        if len(String1) == len(String2):
            return len(String1)
        elif not len(String1) > len(String2):
            return len(String1)
        elif not len(String1) < len(String2):
            return len(String2)

    def Result():
        for i in range(ShorterString()):
            if String1[i] == String2[i]:
                score += 1
        print(score, "/", LongerString(), "Match", float(score / LongerString()) * 100, "%")

String1 = input('Input String1\n')
String2 = input('Input String2\n')
CompareString.Result()
```

When trying to run latter code i get an error message "line 20, in Result
    for i in range(ShorterString()):
NameError: name 'ShorterString' is not defined"

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough.
I get the error message  "line 20, in Result
    for i in range(ShorterString()):
NameError: name 'ShorterString' is not defined"
when i try to run latter code.

Comment: @Juan Edit that into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the immediate problem, you need to call your methods via `self` - ie `self.LongerString()` - and they need to accept `self` as the first argument.

But this isn't really how you use classes. You should write an `__init__` method that takes the two strings and stores them as instance attributes, then refer to those throughout.

(Also note, you should use PEP8 style for your variable names.)

```
class CompareString:

    def __init__(self, string1, string2):
        self.string1 = string1
        self.string2 = string2

    def longer_string(self):
        if len(self.string1) == len(self.string2):
            ...

    def result(self):
         ... call self.longer_string() etc ...

compare = CompareString(string1, string2)
print compare.result()
```

(Also also note, your `longer_string` method could just be `return max(len(self.string1), len(self.string2))`, and your `shorter_string` method similarly.)

(Also also also note, your `result` method should not iterate over a range, but just over `zip(self.string1, self.string2)`, so you don't even need either of those other methods.)